# Group by one of multiple fields matching

Tags: mongodb, group-by

I have a collection of documents (`grades`) with some missing keys like this:

| Name | ID | Github | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 1 |  | 123 |
|  | 1 | PPane | 456 |
| Alice |  | Alice1 | 234 |
|  | 2 | Alice1 | 567 |

I want to group this data by matching any of Name, ID or Github together and collecting the points.
The result should look like this:

| _id | Points |
| --- | --- |
| [Peter, 1, PPane] | [123, 456] |
| [Alice, 2, Alice1] | [234, 567] |

Right now I am doing this in the backend like this:

```
    const students = new Map<string, CourseStudent>();
    const keys = ['Name', 'ID', 'Github'];
    for (const grade of grades) {
      let student: CourseStudent | undefined = undefined;
      for (const key of keys) {
        const value = grade[key];
        if (value && (student = students.get(value))) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!student) {
        const {Name, ID, Github} = grade;
        student = {_id: {Name, ID, Github}, points: []};
      }
      for (const key of keys) {
        const value = grade[key];
        if (value) {
          students.set(value, student);
        }
      }

      student.points.push(grade.points);
    }
    return Array.from(students.values());
```

The data sizes in my use case are 1000-10000 grades (100-1000 students x 10 assignments).
The actual "grade" data contains a lot more fields, most of which are not used for the final result, but keeping all of it in memory can be costly.

Is there a way to achieve this in the database with an aggregation pipeline, e.g. using `$group`?

To start with, here is a non-working aggregation, because it requires ALL fields to match instead of just one:

```
{$group: {_id: ['$Name', '$ID', '$Github'], points: {$push: '$Points'}}},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only 3 keys to use, grouping by one and collecting the 2 others will result in one missing key only:

1. `$group` by `ID` and collect other keys. Assuming there is at least one document per each user which contains the user's `key` (as in your example), this step will result with number of documents as the number of users + 1. Each document contains the user `ID` and `Name` **or** `Github`. One document refer all document without any `ID`.
2. `$match` to keep only the users documents
3. For each user document get all the matching original documents using `$lookup`, we now have the data needed to get them.
4. Group and format the results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$ID", Name: {$first: "$Name"}, Github: {$first: "$Github"}}},
  {$match: {_id: {$ne: null}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {github: "$Github", iD: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {$or: [
                {$eq: ["$$github", "$Github"]},
                {$eq: ["$$iD", "$ID"]}
            ]}
        }},
        {$group: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: {$addToSet: "$Name"},
            Github: {$addToSet: "$Github"},
            ID: {$addToSet: "$ID"},
            Points: {$push: "$Points"}
        }}
      ],
      as: "docs"
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$first: "$docs"}}},
  {$project: {
      _id: [{$first: "$Name"}, {$first: "$ID"}, {$first: "$Github"}],
      Points: 1
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8errCDbQU0C)